# What algorithm does ml.classification.LogisticRegression use in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

The [ml.classification.LogisticRegression](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-classification-regression.html#binomial-logistic-regression) document points to the [logistic regression in spark.mllib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/mllib-linear-methods.html#logistic-regression), which says:

> We implemented two algorithms to solve logistic regression: mini-batch gradient descent and L-BFGS. We recommend L-BFGS over mini-batch gradient descent for faster convergence.

So in spark.mllib there are [LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS) and [LogisticRegressionWithSGD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD). Which one is used in ml.classification.LogisticRegression?

Answer (score 1):

It uses LBFGS algo from breeze library for L2 regularization and OWLQN (which is an extension of LBFGS) for L1 and elastic net regularization